# How to prove a function returns a value

Tags: verification, formal-methods

Say I have the following 2 JavaScript functions for demonstration purposes:

```
function colorize(integer) {
  if (integer === 1) return 'red'
  if (integer === 2) return 'blue'
  if (integer === 3) return 'yellow'
  // ...
  return 'green'
}

function max(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b)
}
```

The specifications are as follows:

1. `colorize`: The function returns only named CSS colors. It doesn't return hex values or anything.
2. `max`: Returns the max value given two integers. The integers have to be within the valid size of integers that JavaScript allows.

Now I would like to *prove* these properties. To prove that the specification matches the implementation.

First thing I consider is, will these functions ever throw an error, assuming they have proper inputs. Technically it *could*. The hardware could cause the browser to have a glitch perhaps, which causes the app to crash right at the moment it is in one of the functions. Or maybe it runs out of memory the moment it enters these functions. So theoretically it's possible to have an error in these functions, even though practically there would never be an error (given proper inputs).

The next thing is, how to go about proving the implementation matches the specification. Let's start with `colorize`. It needs to be shown that it returns only valid css named colors. Then I start thinking, well should it also prove that it *doesn't return anything else*. That is, test for some random out-of-bounds values like `'foo'` or `10`. This makes me start to get confused as to where the line is between exhaustive *testing* vs. *proving*. I can only imagine how to **test** that the implementation matches the specification. I don't see how to **prove** it matches it.

For `max` it is the same thing.

This leads to the main question. How to "prove" `colorize` and `max` match their specifications (as opposed to "test"). At a high level, what is necessary to write something like a unit test but instead a **proof**. Maybe there needs to be some changes to implementation somewhere. It's easy to write unit tests for this, I would just have a list of CSS colors and check each one against some integers. But I would like to see how to do proofs for this sort of example. For `max` I might check the "boundary" values (0, max integer size positive/negative, and a few medium values), and some edge cases like when they were equal. But these approaches aren't formal/proof-driven, they are just based on finding cases we can imagine errors occurring in and writing unit tests for them.

Comment: Do you want a human proof, or a mechanical one? Which tools are you using, and most importantly, which formal [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of JavaScript (which standard, which implementation) do you care about? Formalizing the complete semantics of Javascript is *very* hard!

Comment: You don't. I mean, it's JavaScript ffs - the number of assumptions you'll need to make about the behavior of your runtime environment would make the proof near-worthless even if it was done.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch small-step operational semantics I think, es5 JavaScript. I saw [operational semantics for javascript](http://theory.stanford.edu/people/jcm/papers/aplas08-camera-ready.pdf) (though it is over my head atp). If I were to pick a tool it would be Haskell or Coq, though I only know the very basics of them. I am mainly looking for a high-level description of how to do it and maybe some snippets/examples, not actually the complete formalization :)

Comment: Not sure how I can make this less broad, please let me know. I am mainly looking for a high-level description of what to do like a "how to write unit tests" but "how to write a proof for a javascript function" like the example. I have little to no concept how much work it would actually take, or where to even begin, so knowing even that would be helpful.

Comment: The issue with JavaScript is that *in practice* it depends a lot of the initial environment: JavaScript in a browser (with a DOM) is not the same as JavaScript in `node.js`

Comment: Either one is fine, say chrome or node.js (v8).

Comment: Then I agree with Telastyn's comment: you don't make such a proof

Comment: I'd be interested to know why not. Why it would be worthless, etc. Or perhaps there is a way to _partially_ prove it, to get some benefit out of proof theory here.

Comment: The evil is in the details....

Comment: I disagree with @BasileStarynkevitch and Telastyn. You can make a formal proof, barring glitches in hardware and minutiae of the runtime environment (which doesn't seem relevant for this function). Whether the proof is useful depends on how critical the function is. In this case, it seems it should be easy to prove the function terminates for all possible inputs and its output is a valid CSS color.

Comment: @AndresF. yay! I would love to see what that looks like.

Comment: It seems that what you want is a way to do [Formal Verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) on your code. It's generally impossible on full JS, because `eval` exists, and other reasons. Same for Java, due to reflection and runtime loading of classes. If, however, you restrict yourself to a well-behaved subset of those languages, the methods mentioned in the Wiki will work.

Comment: Let's assume a well-behaved subset of JavaScript then if it helps!

Comment: @Andres F. The usefulness of the proof also depends of the hypothesis describing the JavaScript runtime environment and semantics

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You could restrict the proof to a given subset of environments ("this has been proven to work on Chrome & Firefox"), but more importantly, I doubt these trivial details (simple `if-else`, integer equality comparison and assignment) varies between js runtimes. If advanced features were involved, I'd be inclined to agree with you. But this example is akin to a (very simple) Math proof.

Comment: @Ordous I agree about `eval` et al, but this isn't the case here. He is asking for formal proof for very simple "Math-like" functions like colorize (essentially a mapping of integers to strings) or max... These are indeed well-behaved subsets of practically any language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [Formal Verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification), and is generally impossible in JS. If, however, you restrict yourself to a subset of the language, it becomes tenable. The usefulness of such an analysis is debatable.

It is certainly used for other languages in areas where safety and correctness is of utmost concern, and development speed can take a back seat (read: medical and space industries foremost). This is a developing field and the methods used are constantly being refined. Some of them are mentioned in the Wiki link.

---

Since you asked for an example even if this means restricting yourself to a subset, I'll give you a very simple one. You could expand it to use more lax definitions and add more language features to get to a more usable one, but that takes more time than I am ready to commit here. Do note, that I'm not actively working in this field and writing from memory of several courses in university that I took some 6-8 years ago.

Say you restrict your language to only have 1 datatype - 32 bit 2-complement int and only have these operations on it: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. You have local variables (initialized to 0, unless otherwise specified), that you can assign to via `=`. You also have an `if` statement that can have `<`, `>`, `=` in it, that is followed by an assignment or `return`, and `return` to return an int. You do *not* have any objects, threads, globals or whatevers. For the sake of simplicity, you also do not have method calls (otherwise you'll have to describe how that's done as well). Syntax is vaguely C-like.

Before you run the analyzer, I'll assume that the program actually compiles - no sense doing this otherwise.

Now, you have the method:

```
0    int max(int a, int b) {
1        if (a > b) return a;
2        if (b > a) return b;
3        return a;
4    }
```

And you want to check that it returns the maximum of the two ints. So, the post conditions you want to check are (these are usually written in a different language, since this is the input to the checker, not compiler):

```
res >= a
res >= b
function always returns
```

Now, the last condition is kinda silly. Since it compiles, the compiler already checked that every method termination ends with a return. And, since there are no loop, jump or call semantics in the language (except return), every operation advances control. But in a slightly more complex language this would be an important and difficult thing to check.

So, if you go the route of Model Checking, you just build a state machine that represents every single state that the program can be in. That's `2^32 * 2^32 * 4` (2 int vars and 4 lines to be on). Obviously that's too many states to hold, so we abstract them by the values the vars can take at the time.

You then start from the end and gather the restrictions on your inputs that got you there.

For `ep3` - End Point 3, you return `a`. So you set `res` = `a`. You then step back once, finding all call sites to this `return` (in the case of this language it's always just 1 step back).

You find that you can only get to this `return` if the previous `if` was false. Hence, now you have a restriction - `NOT b > a`. You then step back another time and get the restriction `NOT a > b`. You've now reached the beginning of your method and you have a result: `a` and restrictions on input: `NOT b > a AND NOT a > b`.

Then you use formal logic rules defined on `int` that describe all various restrictions that you can have on variables to show that the restriction you have implies the conditions you want.

Rinse and repeat for the other 2 exit points.

Now you've proved that *if the method returns, it returns the max value*. The 3rd condition that I've skipped proved that it always returns. Hence the program is correct in the semantics given.

---

A less silly example would be:

```
0    int abs(int a) {
1        if (a < 0) return -1 * a;
2        return a;
3    }
```

With the post-condition of:

```
res >= 0
res == a OR res == -a
```

`ep2` is very simple - you get `res == a AND NOT a < 0`, which clearly satisfies our conditions.

`ep1` is tricky, since there are several operations there. The final operation is `a * -1`. This is typically done via a dedicated circuit, but we are essentially interested in everything that it can do to a number expressed in logical rules. For summation this would be something like:

```
a, b -> (res = a + b AND a + b <= MAX_INT AND a + b >= MIN_INT) 
    OR (res = a + b - INT_RANGE AND a + b >= MAX_INT) 
    OR (res = a + b + INT_RANGE AND a + b <= MIN_INT)
```

I'll note again, that since the logic specification is written in a different language, it uses a datatype that is guaranteed to not overflow on these ops.

You can imagine the same thing done for multiplication, explaining the exact pre- and post-conditions of multiplication for overflow.

So now we return to the method at hand and get the following result of the post-conditions:

```
a < 0 AND (
    (res = -a AND -a <= MAX_INT) //No overflow
    OR (res = -a mod INT_RANGE AND -a > MAX_INT) //positive overflow
    OR (res = -a mod INT_RANGE AND -a < MIN_INT) //negative overflow
    )
```

Since this is written in a language with guaranteed no overflows, you can use rules like `a < 0 => -a >= 0`. Do exactly that and you get:

```
(res = -a AND -a >= 0 AND -a <= MAX_INT)
OR (res = -a mod INT_RANGE AND -a >= 0 AND -a > MAX_INT)
OR (res = -a mod INT_RANGE AND -a >= 0 AND -a < MIN_INT)
```

You then eliminate the last expression - it's impossible. You also eliminate the first expression - the post-conditions obviously follow from it.

You're left with the possibility of `res = -a mod INT_RANGE AND -a > MAX_INT`. The last part of this morphs into `a < -MAX_INT`.

The analyzer will then, most likely, say - it can't prove correctness when input is below -MAX_INT. This is the general case of analyzers - most of the time they will not tell you there's a mistake, but rather say they can't prove there isn't one.

---

You can see how this is very tedious, and adding even simple OPs is difficult - you have to completely describe its operation and every possible outcome in your logic of choice. Adding language features will usually give an exponential explosion in complexity and allowing a fully Turing-complete language will make the general case impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

You're testing on a real world environment, and you're trying to prove underlying assumptions you have no control on, namely hardware and javascript implementation.

Let's say for absurd that some sort of proof exists that your code never fails on every single modern piece of hardware and js engine. I could just write another engine where every call to `Math.max` or every `===` comparison horribly crashes everything, and your "proof" would no longer be valid.

That's why developers only write tests for their own code, and assume the underlying framework/engine/hardware is flawless. If they find any bug with major engine/hardware implementations during later testing stages, they'll probably add a test for that specific case and call it a day. Testing someone else's code at a way lower level is simply not feasible in a real world scenario.

Comment: To be fair, `===` _is_ defined pretty explicitly in the language specification. "This proof assumes JavaScript is implemented in accordance with SPEC." can mitigate a lot of that - though I'm not sure the language specification rises to the level needed for an actual proof.

Answer (score 0):

"*"Proof is for mathematical theorems and alcoholic beverages. It's not for science."*" - Michael Mann (I think).

Proof is also not for computer programs either. The nearest you can get to such a "proof" is to follow the lead of science here and statistically demonstrate a strong correlation between your code and the specified output.

One such way of doing this is via tools such as [QuickCheck for testing Haskell programes](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/QuickCheck/). They work on the basis of generating large amounts of random test data based on a formal specification of the function. If the test passes for all test cases, it gives degrees of confidence that the properties of the code meet the spec.

[There appears to be a QuickCheck-inspired JavaScript tool, JSVerify](http://jsverify.github.io/), so this might be worth you checking out.

Comment: I wonder how far AWS goes with Formal Verification. It seems they only do model checking to give a "high degree of confidence" like you say. [Use of Formal Methods at Amazon Web Services](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/formal-methods-amazon.pdf). They used TLA+ to write a formal specification, but not sure where "proofs" come into play, and how they can apply proofs to their setting.

Comment: "Proof is also not for computer programs either." tell that to the branches of Computer Science researching formal proofs (and their limitations, of course). Note that programming language type systems are, in fact, a form of "proof".

Comment: @AndresF, I think you'll find I already did. If it deals with "proof", then it isn't science. So those folk are either confused over what a proof is, or over what their job titles should be (as they are doing maths; not science).

Comment: @DavidArno Computer Science is applied maths. The problem with your assertion is that it runs contrary to the mainstream. Yes, it's your opinion, but it's an *uninformed* opinion. Also, telling researchers "they are confused about their job titles" is slightly condescending and ignorant sounding, don't you think?

Comment: @AndresF., as you know nothing about my education, your assertion that what I'm stating is uniformed opinion is what's know as a baseless assertion. Your turn...

Comment: @AndresF. as a long time professional, I will happily tell those CS folks all about why their research into formal proofs is a waste of time and money. “Beware of bugs in the code... I’ve only proved it correct, not tried it.” ~ Donald Knuth

Comment: @RubberDuck In any field, long time professionals and researchers often walk different paths. This is like a medical doctor saying "as a professional, I've never seen the need to do all that weird stuff biochemists do. I just treat my patients!". In any case, you're wrong: [there exists complex formally verified software](http://ts.data61.csiro.au/projects/TS/l4.verified/), and it's not useless. Here you're preaching to the choir: most readers here will think CS is worthless. Repeat your assertion elsewhere (for example, in cs.stackexchange) and you'd be considered ignorant.

Comment: @AndresF., there may be folk who think CS is worthless. To be honest, i see their views as worthless in turn. My only beef with your comments are that science doesn't deal in proofs (this is a fact; not opinion) and that formal proofs of a specification is limited to edge-cases and is so bogged down with caveats, it's pretty much worthless as a development tool and will likely remain that way for some time.(oh and the fact that you are far too keen to toss personal attacks around, but that's not really of significance).

Comment: @AndresF. I don’t think CS is worthless. I just believe *formal proofs* of software to be a huge waste of time and effort when just as good results can be achieved orders of magnitudes more efficiently with other techniques.

Comment: @DavidArno I didn't say anything personal about you; I said your opinion was uninformed. CS isn't empirical science and it does deal in proof. I wonder -- so as not to make any assumption -- have you studied CS? Because they deal in proof all the time (for example: proof that a given iterative algorithm is equivalent to a recursive one; proof that some property holds for a graph; etc). This is because CS is closer to *applied math* than, say, to biology. A branch of CS studies *proofs*. This is why I called your opinion on this specific topic "uninformed": because it is. It's not personal.

Comment: @RubberDuck when anyone (it could be me!) says "X is worthless in software, I've never used it in all my years of programming", they run the risk of being on the wrong end of [the Blub paradox](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html), only applied to more things than just programming languages, as in the original essay. I constantly question myself to be sure I'm not falling prey to that kind of thinking. Are you?

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, in a Turing Complete language (as JavaScript), [it has been proved impossible to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) write an algorithm that can prove, for every possible function, that it returns (and that's considering only *the code*, without the hardware malfunction you've mentioned).

Pragmatically, you can attain do some properties of your function and make an algorithm that proves that those functions return under certain criteria, for exampe:

- Restrict the conditions to which your proof applies (e.g.: The computer *works* and the input is positive);
- Separate the valid input range into smaller *valid input subranges*;
- Prove that each *valid input subrange* follows a code path that leads to a result.

With this method, both functions that you provide can be *proved to return*.

It is quite normal to make hard assumptions. Most programs suppose, for example, that memory is infinite during production, and then, after profile, publish something like *"this program requires at least 2Gb RAM"*

Also, when you say

> (...) To prove that the specification matches the implementation (...)

And then

> (...)test for some random out-of-bounds values (...)

It seens to me that you're contradicting yourself, because *some random out-of-bounds value* is not in *the specification*.

Comment: Note the halting problem states it's impossible to prove any arbitrary function returns, NOT that a specific function returns. This may seem like a nitpick, but actually a lot of people confuse the two, which is trivially wrong: anyone can prove the js function `function stuff() { return "hey"; }` returns. The same with `max` and `colorize`! Properties can be proven of specific functions, and the Halting Problem is silent on that.

Comment: I've tried to improve the wording. What about now?